# ViewController as delegate of custom view's tableview

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom UIView, MyView, with a couple of tableviews in it  - tv1 and tv2 - both added programmatically.

I have a custom UIViewController, MyController, which creates an instance of MyView on loadView.

My goal is the following. myView should be the datasource and delegate for myView.tv1, since it doesn't touch my data model and is static.

myController should be the delegate of myView.tv2, since its content will depend on the datasource.

I have added the following to each header:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@interface MyView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

and added to each the required delegate methods.

In MyView's init, I add that table views, and set the delegate of the first one to self:

```
tv1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame1 style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tv1.delegate = self;
tv1.datasource = self;

tv2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame2 style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

And in my Controller I connect up the second tableview:

```
- (void)loadView{
self.view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
[(MyView *)self.view tv2].delegate = self;
[(MyView *)self.view tv2].dataSource = self;
}
```

When I run this, I get a whole mess of runtime errors.  Sometimes it complains about a paging control, other times NSCFArray, othertimes no text at all. It always crashes.

I have determined that it is setting the datasource that causes the problem, not the delegate. If I comment out the datasource line in laodView, it runs fine (but with no content of course).

What could cause my to experience a different runtime error each time, and where might I be going wrong?

Comment: Getting varied crash error messages usually (in my experience) has something to do with memory. Have you tried commenting out the implementation of one of the table views and trying to just get them to work 1 at a time?  If you can narrow it down to which tableview (or either) is the problem, that would help in figuring things out.

Comment: To complement the comment by @WendiKidd , see if running the static analyzer helps.

Comment: Thanks - I'm seeing a lot of "[<blank> numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent" messages, where blank is __NSCFType, NCSFArray, etc.  I'm not sure where to start, since I am using ARC.

Comment: is `tv2` a strongly retained property of `MyView`?

Comment: I just have "UITableView *tv2;" in my iVars, and a getter exposing the same - would like to hear more (memory management is not my strongest suit).

Comment: Only a little reading so far, but it seems that an iVar is __strong by default.

Answer (score 0):

> myView should be the datasource and delegate for myView.tv1, since it
>   doesn't touch my data model and is static

That's not really MVC, right ?

I think you'll be able to track the problems faster (or easily avoid it) if you prepared separate combined delegate&datasource classes for each table. The `table1` datasource might be an internal class of `MyView`.

It's critically important to keep the delegate/datasource references retained by the table owner as the table will not retain it itself (that might be not so important for the case when you set the delegate/datasource to `self` both for table1 (MyView) and table2 (MyController), but you need to keep it in mind if you create separate delegate&datasource classes). Anyway you'll need to retain the `array` you are using as a datasource.

Comment: Thanks - how would I retain the tableview? I am using ARC.  As for MVC, that's the main reason I'm managing the delegate/datasource for tv2 separately.  tv1 simply updates it's display based on button presses within the same View, with no reference to any data objects etc - this code will always be the same no matter which controller I connect the view to, so why should the controller have to assume responsibilty for it?

Comment: I'm not using ARC, but it must be `strong` argument that you need to make ARC to take the property ownership (@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject * myString;). As for the `table1` delegate, i don't mean it to be even mentioned at `MyController`, you can declare it's interface and write it's implementation at `MyView.m`, create there it's instance, retain it and set to be the delegate of `table1`. The `table1` initialization might be wrapped at `MyView` method declared at `MyView.h` so that `MyController` will know nothing about it's delegate.

Comment: We may have crossed wires - tv1 is entirely built and controlled inside MyView, as you suggest.  MyController only has knowledge of tv2.  I am not using a property to define tv2 at the moment.

Comment: Of course it depends on what are your needs. Keeping the table and it's delegate private seems reasonable from the encapsulation perspective, you can always use kind of a direct (messages not to the table, but to view that handles it) or provider-driven (e.g. notifications) communication interface, i believe in the good hands this would be 'wireless' as the design is under control. As for tv2, there's no need i can see to make a property, just be careful not to release the ivar (it is retained by alloc allright).